# Changing Kibana's xpack settings via API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I wish to increase the timeout for CSV report generation on Kibana, but I don't have access to the `kibana.yml` file to change the `xpack.reporting.queue.timeout` value. Is there a way I can change it via the API method using Dev Tools? Also, do I need to restart the Kibana and ES nodes after changing the value, or will it take effect automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If by "not having access to `kibana.yml`", you mean that you are running on Elastic Cloud, then you can change that setting from the Cloud UI in the Kibana settings. [The documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/reporting-settings-kb.html#reporting-job-queue-settings) shows the cloud icon, meaning that's editable on cloud.

If not, you can't modify this. DevTools only communicates with Elasticsearch but this is a Kibana setting.
And this setting is not available either in the [Kibana Advanced Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/advanced-options.html).

Comment: I'm not running on Elastic Cloud either. Seems like I won't be able to modify this setting then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You need to ask the admin I guess.